# Check what partition is used?

Tags: linux, shell, kernel, partition, rootfs

I'm working on a SBC6845 card with Linux on it:
 I have 4 partitions installed:

```
Creating 5 MTD partitions on "atmel_nand":
0x000000000000-0x000000100000 : "Factory"
0x000000100000-0x000000300000 : "Kernel1"
0x000000300000-0x000000500000 : "Kernel2"
0x000000500000-0x000008280000 : "Rootfs1"
0x000008280000-0x000010000000 : "Rootfs2"
```

I want to make a shell script that display which partition is currently used but I don't see how.

the command "df -h" returns:

```
# df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root               178.8G     65.4G    104.3G  39% /
tmpfs                    61.7M         0     61.7M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    61.7M     36.0K     61.7M   0% /tmp
```

and also `fdisk` doesn't work on this system.

Anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38870/how-to-check-if-a-filesystem-is-mounted-with-a-script

Comment: nah this doesnt help me..

Comment: @AK_, I don't see how the linked question is related to this one.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by `which partition is used`?

Comment: Which partition i'm in? I want to know so that when I execute some script in this specific partition I save it in the other partition (rootfs2 or rootfs1). For exemple I'm in Kernel 1, then I know I can do stuff on Kernel 2. I'm sorry it's not very understanding but I just want to find a way to see in what partition i'm currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to know on which partition your script is currently located ? `df` can help you with this! You just have to give it the path to your script as an argument:

```
#!/bin/sh
df $0  | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

And `sh myscript.sh` gives me: `/dev/sda1`

Explanations:

- `df $0` outputs the partition in which `myscript.sh` is
- `tail -1` ignores the first line of `df` (name of the columns)
- `awk '{print $1}'` returns the first column of `df`, which is the partition

I hope this is what you expected!

Comment: Sorry i'm kinda new to partitioning in linux but what is sda1?
I mean, compared to Kernel1, Rootfs, etc..
Maybe I need to mount sda1 or something?

Comment: Actually, I don't know how did you get these partition names. What was the command you used?

Comment: It's when I reboot my SBC6845 card, it shows many informations like this. Maybe it's too specific :/ but df returns me as first line /dev/root, does it mean it's the partition used?

Comment: Yes it does, according to `man df`.